# How do I search a map based on another map

Tags: flutter, dart

i have  map  and list  have names of keys

```dart
first map =[1  : "value" ,  2 : "value" , 3: "value" , 4: "value"  ];
second map = [1 , 3];
```

so how i can search  by second map in first map
thanks for anyhelp

Comment: `var results = [for (var key in map2) map1[key]];`